# list.pop() работает не так как нужно

Tags: python, list

Вот код:

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
y.pop(1)
print(x)
```

Мне в программе нельзя менять список `x`, и чтобы производить разные метаморфозы (например list.pop()), я копирую его в переменную `y`, но когда я удаляю элемент из списка `y`, он также удаляется и в `x`. Код выше выводит в консоль `[1,3]`, хотя задумывалось что будет выводиться `[1,2,3]`. Как это исправить?

Comment: Вы копируете ссылку на список, а не сам список.

Comment: Именно со  списками в питоне есть "специальный" способ копирования!!! `y = x[:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно присвоить `y` копию списка `x`. А вы ссылаетесь `y` на тот же объект в памяти, что и `x`.

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = x.copy()
y.pop(1)
print(x)
```